# Using <Navigate> with `react-router-dom` and `next.js`

Tags: next.js, react-router

So I have a slightly weird setup where I redirect all routes where I need dynamic routing to `index.tsx` and use `react-router-dom` to handle those routes Client-side. I mainly had to do this because it seems that when exporting Next.js sites to a static site, Next.js generates pages for each route, so I can't generate new routes in Javascript.

However, this setup doesn't seem work properly when using `react-router-dom`'s `<Navigate />` component. For example,

```
// index.tsx
const Home: FC = () => {
  // Currently going to generate the room id locally, but we
  // should do this server side so that we can guarantee uniqueness.

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<RedirectToMain />} />
        <Route path="/:roomId" element={<Main />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

const RedirectToMain: FC = () => {
  const generatedRoomId = Array(5)
    .fill(null)
    .map(x => alphabet[Math.floor(26 * Math.random())])
    .join('');

  console.log('navigating');
  return <Navigate to={generatedRoomId} />;
}

const Main: FC = () => {
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  console.log(roomId);

  // We must wait for roomId to load before running.
  if (!roomId || roomId.length === 0) {
    return <></>;
  }
  return (
    <WebSocketProvider roomId={roomId}>
      <MinesAppBar url={`http://mineswpr.io/${roomId}`} />
      <Board />
    </WebSocketProvider>
  );
};
```

When running this locally with `yarn next dev`, it redirects to `localhost:3000/ABCDE` and then the url changes back to `localhost:3000/`. When running this as a static site which is setup to redirect all traffic to `/index.html`, it seems to constantly call `<Navigate />`.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### You need to use useNavigate hook instead of Navigate

the Navigate component works in React component classes,
quoting the react-router-dom docs

[> use this feature in a React.Component subclass where hooks are not able to be used](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate#:%7E:text=feature%20in%20a%20React.Component%20subclass%20where%20hooks%20are%20not%20able%20to%20be%20used.)

and since you're using functional components you should instead be using hooks therefore your code should look something like this

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
const testFn = () => { return navigate('/') }
```